# How to change some keywords color in Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

How to change some keywords color in Android Studio? To better understand what I mean look at the image. Note that bottom method keywords **final** and **var** have the same color as variable name itself (then try to compare with the first screenshot).

I did not find the option to set color for a particular keyword in Android Studio Color Cheme. Is it possible? Perhaps the the same is true for IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

Comment: Check the Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Java -> **Keywords**. See [Customize a color scheme](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#customize-color-scheme). Make also sure the file is located under the Java **source root** directory.

Comment: @Andrey Do you really understand the question? By the way it's not a java but that does not change the question.

Comment: Sorry, for Kotlin it will be Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | **Kotlin**. If you want to change **some** keywords - (instead of all them having same colors) - it is not possible.

Comment: Wish this was possible too, because it's often hard to see functions in a see of variables and whatnot